# SQLite query on Android?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE APTable (id_Ap INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
SSID TEXT, 
BSSID TEXT,
Id_APtest INTEGER NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (Id_APtest) REFERENCES Tests (id_test) ON DELETE CASCADE)

CREATE TABLE APmeasure (id_APmeasure INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
RSSI TEXT,
TimeOfMeasure DATETIME,
BSSID TEXT,
id_APm INTEGER NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (id_APm) REFERENCES APTable (id_Ap) ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

I want to check if exists one `id_Ap` in `APTable` where `BSSID = x` and `id_Aptest=y`, and return the value of `id_Ap`.

How can I do this in a Android API query?

Answer (score 0):

```java
// pass in x and y (must be strings or converted to strings) as query
// parameters to the database query.
Cursor cursor = db.query("APTable",
    new String[] { "id_Ap" },
    "BSSID = ? AND ip_Aptest = ?",
    new String[] { x, y },
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null);

// get the value of id_Ap
int id = cursor.getInt(0);
```